# Storing L2 tick data with Python

Tags: python, numpy

Preamble:

- I am working with L2 tick data.
- The bid/offer will not necessarily be balanced in terms of number of levels
- The number of levels could range from 0 to 20.
- I want to save the full book to disk every time it is updated
- I *believe* I want to use numpy array such that I can use h5py/vaex to perform offline data processing.
- I'll ideally be writing (appending) to disk every x updates or on a timer.

If we assume an example book looks like this:

```py
array([datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 6, 14, 57, 8, 532152),                       # book creation time
       array(['20171106-14:57:08.528', '20171106-14:57:08.428'], dtype='<U21'), # quote entry (bid)
       array([1.30699, 1.30698]),                                               # quote price (bid)
       array([100000., 250000.]),                                               # quote size (bid)
       array(['20171106-14:57:08.528'], dtype='<U21'),                          # quote entry (offer)
       array([1.30709]),                                                        # quote price (offer)
       array([100000.])],                                                       # quote size (offer)
       dtype=object)
```

Numpy doesnt like the jagged-ness of the array, and whilst I'm happy (enough) to use `np.pad` to pad the times/prices/sizes to a length of 20, I don't *think* I want to be creating an array for the book creation time.

Could/should I be going about this differently? Ultimately I'll want to do asof joins against the a list of trades hence I'd like a column-store approach. How is everyone else doing this? Are they storing multiple rows? or multiple columns?

**EDIT:**

I want to be able to do something like:

```
with h5py.File("foo.h5", "w") as f:
    f.create_dataset(data=my_np_array)
```

and then later perform an asof join between my hdf5 tickdata and a dataframe of trades.

**EDIT2:**

In KDB the entry would look like:

```
q)t:([]time:2017.11.06D14:57:08.528;sym:`EURUSD;bid_time:enlist 2017.11.06T14:57:08.528 20171106T14:57:08.428;bid_px:enlist 1.30699, 1.30698;bid_size:enlist 100000. 250000.;ask_time:enlist 2017.11.06T14:57:08.528;ask_px:enlist 1.30709;ask_size:enlist 100000.)
q)t
time                          sym    bid_time                                        bid_px          bid_size      ask_time                ask_px  ask_size
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017.11.06D14:57:08.528000000 EURUSD 2017.11.06T14:57:08.528 2017.11.06T14:57:08.428 1.30699 1.30698 100000 250000 2017.11.06T14:57:08.528 1.30709 100000  
q)first t
time    | 2017.11.06D14:57:08.528000000
sym     | `EURUSD
bid_time| 2017.11.06T14:57:08.528 2017.11.06T14:57:08.428
bid_px  | 1.30699 1.30698
bid_size| 100000 250000f
ask_time| 2017.11.06T14:57:08.528
ask_px  | 1.30709
ask_size| 100000f
```

**EDIT3:**

Should I just give in with the idea of a nested column and have 120 columns (20*(bid_times+bid_prices+bid_sizes+ask_times+ask_prices+ask_sizes)? Seems excessive, and unwieldy to work with...

Comment: not really sure what is the question here. please clarify. From what I understand, why not use pandas? allows you to manipulate data easily and save to csv file

Comment: Maybe you should use JSON

Comment: @Roim - can I save down dataframes with nested data?

Comment: @Chris - can I memory-map json?

Comment: You can: save a tuple, that is save a string (x, y) and when you read it, parse it accordingly; or separate it into two columns:  entry_bid_1 and entry_bid_2.

Comment: This is more of a project than a SO question... Important early questions include how much data you expect, where it will come from (and in what form), what kinds of metrics you intend to calculate (or what else you intend to do with the data)...

Comment: @sabik, data is coming from a provider via FIX protocol (that's the easy part). Assume a handful ticks per second per lets say 40 crosses to begin with. Data will likely be partitioned on disk by date and symbol (ala KDB). Primary use is for TCA, secondary use might be liquidity analysis. Analytics will be done via Python, vaex looks good. Just need to write down in a format that can be memory-mapped back again.

Comment: Have a look at Man Group's Arctic project. https://github.com/man-group/arctic

Comment: * Will the data be memory-mappable, or will there be too much? Twenty levels down the order book, there's going to be a lot of updates... and the limiting factor is the maximum, not typical amount.
 * For TCA, most of the metrics don't need 20 levels, they need half a level — best bid/offer price only (not volume). It may be worth considering how to support that.
 * The real-time aspects are going to pervade everything that needs to be real-time; to what extent can you dump to disk/queue, then do the actual conversion and analysis later?

Comment: @sabik, analysis is 'offline', might be next-day, might be 5 minutes later, hence data needs to be on-disk within a reasonable amount of time (could queue for e.g. 1 min and flush for example. [vaex](https://github.com/vaexio/vaex) will be used for the data access side. I just need to write the data down. Per my last edit, perhaps many columns is the appropriate approach here - but would need smarts around performing e.g. vwap calc (rather than dumbly pulling all e.g. 40 cols (size+price)

Comment: A columnar data store would do that for you; otherwise, you could save an L1 copy of the data (either immediately or later), so each metric can use whichever is more appropriate. (Possibly even less than L1, hardly any L1-only metrics actually use the quote sizes; conversely, for the L2 data, you might also want the quote count at each level.) Anyway, hopefully some of this helps!

Comment: @sabik, true, absolute first case is just simply TOB mid, but I'd like to have the write-down support multiple levels from the start i.e. so you could just take `.5*(bid[0]+ask[0])`, but looks like it'll have to be `.5*bid0+ask0`. Currently taking me 150us to create my 'book' from a bunch of quotes. I'll likely ask a fresh question for optimising that.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone is stumbling across this ~2 years later, I have recently revisited this code and have swapped out h5py for pyarrow+parquet.

This means I can create a schema with nested columns and read that back into a pandas DataFrame with ease:

```py
    import pyarrow as pa

    schema = pa.schema([
        ("Time", pa.timestamp("ns")),
        ("Symbol", pa.string()),
        ("BidTimes", pa.list_(pa.timestamp("ns"))),
        ("BidPrices", pa.list_(pa.float64())),
        ("BidSizes", pa.list_(pa.float64())),
        ("BidProviders", pa.list_(pa.string())),
        ("AskTimes", pa.list_(pa.timestamp("ns"))),
        ("AskPrices", pa.list_(pa.float64())),
        ("AskSizes", pa.list_(pa.float64())),
        ("AskProviders", pa.list_(pa.string())),
    ])
```

In terms of streaming the data to disk, I use `pq.ParquetWriter.write_table` - keeping track of open filehandles (one per Symbol) so that I can append to the file, only closing (and thus writing metadata) when I'm done.

Rather than streaming pyarrow tables, I stream regular Python dictionaries, creating a Pandas DataFrame when I hit a given size (e.g. 1024 rows) which I then pass to the ParquetWriter to write down.