# Fastest way to turn many lists into single np array with predefined datatypes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a better (faster) approach to writing into a predefined 1D numpy array than iterating? Could I write >1 elements at a time? Would that be faster?

I tried padding the arrays then using `np.concatenate()` but it was significantly slower.

I hoped I could do something like `e[0][1:1+len(times)] = times`, but that isn't indexing in the dimension I require.

Here is some example code, key thing to note is that I have more columns than data, I'm creating a column-store, so I need to record empty values...

```py
import numpy as np

# quote has arrived with 2 levels
time = 1509980228568000
times = [1509980228528000, 1509980228528000]
prices = [1.80699, 1.80698]
sizes = [100000.0, 250000.0]

# assume this is my 'schema'
number_of_levels = 4
dtypes = [('time', 'uint64'),
          ('bid_time0', 'uint64'), ('bid_time1', 'uint64'), ('bid_time2', 'uint64'), ('bid_time3', 'uint64'),
          ('bid_px0', 'float64'), ('bid_px1', 'float64'), ('bid_px2', 'float64'), ('bid_px3', 'float64'),
          ('bid_size0', 'float64'), ('bid_size1', 'float64'), ('bid_size2', 'float64'), ('bid_size3', 'float64')]
# create empty shell array
e = np.zeros(1, dtype=dtypes)

# add time
e[0][0] = time

# insert bid times
offset = 1
for i in range(min(number_of_levels, len(times))):
    e[0][offset+i] = times[i]

# insert bid prices
offset += number_of_levels
for i in range(min(number_of_levels, len(prices))):
    e[0][offset+i] = prices[i]

# insert bid sizes
offset += number_of_levels
for i in range(min(number_of_levels, len(sizes))):
    e[0][offset+i] = sizes[i]
```

Alternatively - if there is a better approach to what I'm doing, I'm all ears :)

**Note:** This is a slightly noddy example, `number_of_levels` is larger (but still only ~20) in practice,

Answer (score 1):

```
# Create your row
row = [time] + times[:min(number_of_levels, len(times))] + \
    [0] * (number_of_levels - min(number_of_levels, len(times))) + \
    prices[:min(number_of_levels, len(prices))] + \
    [0] * (number_of_levels - min(number_of_levels, len(prices))) + \
    sizes[:min(number_of_levels, len(sizes))] + \
    [0] * (number_of_levels - min(number_of_levels, len(sizes)))

# Create a numpy array
arr = np.array(tuple(row), dtype=dtypes)

# Create a new array with supposedly with new data
arr2 = np.array(tuple(row), dtype=dtypes)

# Stack them up
arr3 = np.vstack((arr, arr2))
```

Comment: Your setup is unfair. You have to include np.array creation in yours.  e = np.empty(1, dtype=dtypes).  On my computer your setup including np.array creation was 1.764432447 seconds while mine  was 1.509480661 seconds.  Anyway, it is difficult to optimize when you don't see the  whole picture. Trying to optimize entire program may be more effective than just one row.  Perhaps, there is a way to use vector operation in numpy.

Comment: If you want to keep e = np.empty(1, dtype=dtypes), replace the last line with e[0] = tuple(row). It still outperforms the original code. On my computer, 0.37596905999999997 vs 0.629686423.

Comment: This works out faster. `79.8 usec` vs `116 usec` per loop, so a decent improvement! I used `np.hstack` as I'm building columns. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

So you've made an array with 1 element, and 13 fields

```
In [241]: e                                                                                          
Out[241]: 
array([(55309248, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.)],
      dtype=[('time', '<u8'), ('bid_time0', '<u8'), ('bid_time1', '<u8'), ('bid_time2', '<u8'), ('bid_time3', '<u8'), ('bid_px0', '<f8'), ('bid_px1', '<f8'), ('bid_px2', '<f8'), ('bid_px3', '<f8'), ('bid_size0', '<f8'), ('bid_size1', '<f8'), ('bid_size2', '<f8'), ('bid_size3', '<f8')])
```

You can assign a tuple to an element of that array - just make match the number of fields:

```
In [246]: e[0]                                                                                       
Out[246]: (55309248, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.)
In [247]: e[0]=tuple(range(13))                                                                      
In [248]: e                                                                                          
Out[248]: 
array([(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10., 11., 12.)],
      dtype=[('time', '<u8'), ('bid_time0', '<u8'), ('bid_time1', '<u8'), ('bid_time2', '<u8'), ('bid_time3', '<u8'), ('bid_px0', '<f8'), ('bid_px1', '<f8'), ('bid_px2', '<f8'), ('bid_px3', '<f8'), ('bid_size0', '<f8'), ('bid_size1', '<f8'), ('bid_size2', '<f8'), ('bid_size3', '<f8')])
```

I won't try to work out your mix of ranges and mapping from the variables.  That's your task.

Data for a structured array can be in the form of a list of tuples.  But often there are many more records than fields, so it is relatively efficient to assign values to all records, field by field.

It might be easier to define multidimensional fields:

```
In [249]: dt = [('time', 'uint64'), 
     ...:    ('bid_time', 'uint64', (4,)), ('bid_px', 'float64', (4,)), ('bid_size', 'float64', (4,))] 
                                                                                      
In [250]: dt                                                                                         
Out[250]: 
[('time', 'uint64'),
 ('bid_time', 'uint64', (4,)),
 ('bid_px', 'float64', (4,)),
 ('bid_size', 'float64', (4,))]
In [251]: e = np.zeros(3, dt)                                                                        
In [252]: e                                                                                          
Out[252]: 
array([(0, [0, 0, 0, 0], [0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0.]),
       (0, [0, 0, 0, 0], [0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0.]),
       (0, [0, 0, 0, 0], [0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0.])],
      dtype=[('time', '<u8'), ('bid_time', '<u8', (4,)), ('bid_px', '<f8', (4,)), ('bid_size', '<f8', (4,))])
In [253]: e['time']=[1,2,3]                                                                          
In [254]: e['bid_size']                                                                              
Out[254]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Then you could assign multiple values at once

```
e['bid_time'] = ...
```

Comment: Per my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62980473/storing-l2-tick-data-with-python) question I wanted to write down nested arrays but can't, hence having a column per field. The workflow is to receive a quote, turn it into a 121-item  np.array (20*3*2 + 1, levels*(price+size+time)*(bid+ask) + created_time) and then write to a h5py file (TODO: cache and write down every X seconds or when num_quotes > threshold)